# Error in Carousel slider codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am new to codeigniter i don't know how to display carousel slider in codeigniter

```
<div class="contact-form">
    <div class="carousel slide" id="fade-quote-carousel" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="3000">
        <!-- Carousel indicators -->
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
            <li data-target="#fade-quote-carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
            <li data-target="#fade-quote-carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
            <li data-target="#fade-quote-carousel" data-slide-to="2" ></li>
            <li data-target="#fade-quote-carousel" data-slide-to="3"></li>
            <li data-target="#fade-quote-carousel" data-slide-to="4"></li>
            <li data-target="#fade-quote-carousel" data-slide-to="5"></li>
        </ol>
        <!-- Carousel items -->
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <?php
            foreach($testimonials as $t)
            {
            ?>
            <?php 

            ?>
            <div class="active item">
                <div class="profile-circle" style="background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.2);">
                <img class="profile-circle" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>uploads/images/testimonials/<?php echo $t->picture; ?>" alt="testimonials_image">
                </div>
                <blockquote>
                    <p><?php echo $t->content; ?></p>
                </blockquote>
            </div>
            <?php
            }
            ?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

this is the code , actually i know what the error is but i dont know how to rectify it , ie , at the first excecution the division class must be **active item** and after first excecution the class need to be only **item**.

Comment: Why don't you add a simple counter in your loop? If 0, echo "active". If you are sure that this is the problem, i can answer to you with the code.

Comment: yes sure that is the problem

Comment: i Have a little doubt here, im doing a cms site where a clinte if he wants to add another carousel page then he should be able to do successfully, this solution works fine for me but the issue im facing is with the indicators how to increase it from 3 to 5 when the clint add one or more image for his end ? i mean to say how to show it as 3 indicators instead of 5 when the clint add two more carousel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are sure that the problem is the class `"active"` for the first element only, you can do something like this, in your foreach:

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <?php
    $counter = 0; 
    //add a counter and check its value in your div. 
    //If it's 0, echo active, otherwise nothing. 
    //In the end of your loop, the counter increases so it won't be 0 again

    foreach ($testimonials as $t) {
    //next div will echo "active", if the $counter==0

        ?>
        <div class="item <?= ($counter == 0) ? "active" : "" ?>">
            <div class="profile-circle" style="background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.2);">
                <img class="profile-circle" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>uploads/images/testimonials/<?php echo $t->picture; ?>" alt="testimonials_image">
            </div>
            <blockquote>
                <p><?php echo $t->content; ?></p>
            </blockquote>
        </div>
        <?php

        //increase the $counter, or set it another value in order not to echo "active" again for the next loops
        $counter++;
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: i Have a little doubt here, im doing a cms site where a clinte if he wants to add another carousel page then he should be able to do successfully, this solution works fine for me but the issue im facing is with the indicators how to increase it from 3 to 5 when the clint add one or more image for his end ? i mean to say how to show it as 3 indicators instead of 5 when the clint add two more carousel